# NSdictionary crashes app when tried to load into tableviewcell

Tags: ios, xcode

i am writting an app that loads data retrieved from mysql database into a table view via NSMutableArray nd NSdictionary usage. and i fear i am making a mistake in the NSDictionary bit..

i have 2 control NSMutableArrays that load correctly into the table cells but once i try to split up my recieved NSDictionary nd load the data in keys "Name" and "Artist" into the cells it crashes. please help me identify the bug.

i know the problem is not the php or dictionary because i log the recieved dictionary and the output is very intact. (pasted below)

```
2012-08-28 15:53:52.339 es[11783:c07] {
Artist = "K-Phlowz";
Likes = 27;
Link = "http://localhost/SNTestFiles/Music/K-PHLOWZ-BENOITSHIT.mp3";
Name = "Benoit Shit";
PhotoLink = "http://localhost/SNTestFiles/Photos/TopMusic/K-PHLOWZ-BENOITSHIT.jpg";
}
```

however, when i declare an NSDictionary in the tableviewcell method it crashes and therefore when i try to load the strings in "name" and "Artist" into the cell.labeltext and cell.detaillabeltext, it doesnt work. Please help me identify the problem and/or let me know if a more accurate way to work through this problem. (Source code is pasted below).

feel free to copy and paste into your xcode to help identify issues clearly..

```
// ChanViewController.h
// es
//
// Created by Nnamdi Okeke on 8/7/12.
// Copyright (c) 2012 Bubble Technology. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define kGETUrl @"http://localhost/SNTestFiles/PHPFiles/FetchSongs.php?Artist=%@"

@interface ChanViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

{
NSDictionary *stuff;
IBOutlet UILabel *label;
NSMutableArray *jams;
NSMutableArray *artists;
NSMutableArray *json;
IBOutlet UITableView *songs;
IBOutlet UILabel *artist;
IBOutlet UIImageView *ArtistCovers;
} 
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *ArtistCovers;

-(IBAction)back:(id)sender;

@end


// ChanViewController.m
// es
//
// Created by Nnamdi Okeke on 8/7/12.
// Copyright (c) 2012 Bubble Technology. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ChanViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"




@implementation ChanViewController

@synthesize ArtistCovers; 

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
// Custom initialization
}
return self;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad
{

//--------------------------------passing in data from homepage---------------

AppDelegate *artistname = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[artist setText:artistname.artistsnames];



//----------------------------------Fetchin Cover Photos---------------------------

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/SNTestFiles/Photos/ArtistCovers/%@.jpg", artist.text];

UIImage *ArtistCover = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];

[ArtistCovers setImage:ArtistCover];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.





//----------------------------test nsmutablearrays-------------------------------

jams = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Medusa", @"Toyin", @"So Incredible", @"I Don Hammer",@"Dami Duro", @"Senrenre", @"Sisi Nene", @"Benoit Shit", @"Dance For Me", @"Tom Ford Flow", @"Magic", @"Gidi Swag", @"Aunty Dupe", nil];

artists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Tobias", @"DRBLasgidi", @"JRah", @"T-Topz",@"Davido", @"Ajebutter22", @"Wizkid", @"K-Phlowz", @"Wizkid", @"DRBLasgidi", @"L.O.S", @"Ajebutter22", @"Joules Da Kidd", nil];

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



NSString *fetchjamsurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:kGETUrl, artist.text];
NSData *fetchjamsdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fetchjamsurl]];
NSError *e;
json = (NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:fetchjamsdata options:kNilOptions error:&e];
NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", info);
label.text = [info objectForKey:@"Artist"];

}

-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [json count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return 40;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}


/////////////////////// -- THE PROBLEM -- \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
//                                                                        \\
//                                                                        //
    stuff = (NSDictionary *)[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//                                                                        \\
//                                                                        \\
////////////////////////////////////////////\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\


//-------------------------test strings for cells-----------------------

NSString *SongTitle = [[jams objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
NSString *ArtistNames = [[artists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Artist"];

//------------------------------------------------------------------------


NSString *SongTitlejson = [stuff objectForKey:@"Name"];
NSString *ArtistNamesjson = [stuff objectForKey:@"Artist"];



cell.textLabel.text = SongTitlejson;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = ArtistNamesjson;
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Heiti TC" size:18];
cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Heiti TC" size:11];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];



UIButton *AddToPlaylist = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
AddToPlaylist.frame = CGRectMake(240, 5, 30, 30);
[AddToPlaylist setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addtoplaylist.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[AddToPlaylist addTarget:self action:@selector(AddToPlaylists:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIButton *LikeSong = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
LikeSong.frame = CGRectMake(280, 5, 30, 30);
[LikeSong setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CellLike.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[LikeSong addTarget:self action:@selector(Like:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell addSubview:AddToPlaylist];
[cell addSubview:LikeSong];

return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

>
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Thanks Alot guys

Comment: I think it is not returning the NSDictionary type.Can u post the response which you are getting from Server?

Comment: One thing that would help is if you posted details on what the crash actually is.

Comment: Try *not* declaring it in .h, and instantiating it only in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.  Just put `NSDictionary *` before `stuff = (NSDictionary *)[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: @Tendulkar the response is the first block of code i posted..         {
Artist = "K-Phlowz";
Likes = 27;
Link = "http://localhost/SNTestFiles/Music/K-PHLOWZ-BENOITSHIT.mp3";
Name = "Benoit Shit";
PhotoLink = "http://localhost/SNTestFiles/Photos/TopMusic/K-PHLOWZ-BENOITSHIT.jpg";
}

Comment: @AMayes hi.. i removed the declaration from the .h file.. and added the NSDictionary but it still crashed.. however when i declare the NSDictionary outside the cellforrowindex method.. the application runs.. but i cant do that because i need to use index.row which only works in the mothod. Any other ideas?

Comment: @CarlVeazey the message says: thread 1: Program Recieved Signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS.. but doesnt log any error message.. just the server output dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  The solution to your problem is to declare stuff in .h, and either @property and @synthesize it, or to initialize it in -init with `NSDictionary *stuff = [NSDictionary new];` or something along those lines.  Then you can set `stuff` to `(NSDictionary *)[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` without having a problem.  (This is assuming that json is interchangeable with NSDictionary.)

Note that the problem is that stuff has not been initialized, so the compiler has not allocated any memory for it at runtime.  The other possibility is, of course, that your json object is not compatible with the NSDictionary class.

Comment: Hey thanks for that.. but it still didnt work.. could you copy the code i uploaded and make the corrections incase im not doing it too right..  please.

Comment: lol!  Stick this: `json = [NSMutableArray new];` right before this: `json = (NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:fetchjamsdata options:kNilOptions error:&e];
`

Comment: Okay so now we've made progress.. i have gotten the received NSDictionary to fill into the table cells. BUT.. this is the problem.. -When the NSMutable array returned from the server has only one object, the app will only run properly if the "numberofRowsinSection" has return 1; instead of return [json count];. same goes for instances tht return 2 or more objects from the server. basically the app only crashes when return [json count]; is implemented. which is simply unacceptable.. any ideas guys?... thanks alot.

Comment: A hack until you can figure it out is the following: `int i = 1;  if ([json count] > 1){ i = [json count];}  return i;`